# Integration of a vector valued function using odeint in two-dimensions

Tags: python, function, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I am trying to expand the idea [given here](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2011-May/029502.html) for an one-dimensional integral of a vector-valued function using `odeint` to **two-dimensions**, in an approach that is analogous to what is done in `dblquad`.

Below you can see my current attempt:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def _infunc(x, func, gfun, hfun, more_args):
    a = gfun(x)
    b = hfun(x)
    y0 = f(x, a)
    return odeint(lambda v, y: f(x, y, *more_args), y0=y0, t=[a, b] )[1]

def dblodeint(f, a, b, gfun, hfun, args=()):
    y0 = f(a, gfun(a), *args)
    return odeint(lambda v, y: _infunc(y, f, gfun, hfun, args),
                  y0=y0, t=[a, b])[1]

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    def f(x, y):
        return np.array([x*y**2, x**2*y, x**4*y, x**6*y], float)

    def exact_int(a, b, ya, yb):
        return np.array([(b**2-a**2)*(yb**3-ya**3)/6.,
                         (b**3-a**3)*(yb**2-ya**2)/6.,
                         (b**5-a**5)*(yb**2-ya**2)/10.,
                         (b**7-a**7)*(yb**2-ya**2)/14.], float)

    print 'approx:', dblodeint(f, 0, 10, lambda x:0, lambda x:10)

    print 'exact:', exact_int(0, 10, 0, 10)
```

Unfortunately this is not working... the following result is given which is wrong:

```
approx:Repeated convergence failures (perhaps bad Jacobian or tolerances).
Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
exact: [  1.66666667e+04   1.66666667e+04   1.00000000e+06   7.14285714e+07]
```

Comment: Say more - in what way is it not working?  Good ways to do that:  Post an exception if you got an exception, or post input data, desired output data, and current, incorrect output data, or describe the problem in some way.

Comment: This code, copied exactly, works fine on my system. Current system: OSX numpy and scipy compiled with intel compilers and the `mkl` library.

Comment: Likewise - I'm running numpy 1.8.0.dev-b375592, scipy 0.13.0.dev-fe8b0a5, both built using gcc/gfortran 4.7 against OpenBLAS on Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: @Ophion so I guess the bug is here... I'm using Numpy 1.7 with Python 2.7 64bit on... Windows 7 (the problem)... Thank you for the feedbacks...

Comment: @ali_m so I guess the bug is here... I'm using Numpy 1.7 with Python 2.7 64bit on... Windows 7 (the problem)... Thank you for the feedbacks..

Comment: @SaulloCastro it also works for me using numpy 1.7.1 and scipy 0.11.0, if that helps to narrow it down

Comment: @ali_m I will have a look at this and let you know what the problem was...

Comment: @ali_m When you ran this, how did your output look like, I tried running in my Anaconda environment and I got the same error... did you get `approx: something different of [0. 0. 0. 0.]`?

Comment: @SaulloCastro I get `approx: [  1.66666667e+04   1.66666667e+04   1.00000000e+06   7.14285714e+07]
exact: [  1.66666667e+04   1.66666667e+04   1.00000000e+06   7.14285714e+07]`